# Strange problem while compiling CHM file

Tags: html, documentation, html-help-workshop

I had to write some documentation. I wrote each page in MS Word and then save each *.docx as htm file. I'm using "HTML Help Workshop" (from microsoft) to compile a chm file.

I was able to sucessfully create a chm file but the problem is that not all images in chm file are displayed. I tried decompiling the *.chm file into another folder and opened each .htm file in web browser. All images are correctly displayed.

Then why aren't they displayed in chm file. Strangely, only some of them aren't displayed. I checked if image format is causing problem, but all images are of same format. I checked if file naming is a problem, but all images are named like image[001-100].jpg in their corresponding folders.

Any idea about whats going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

HTML Help Workshop (HHW) is known to have problems with the HTML generated by Word (or better put: Word generates terrible HTML). Some versions put VML coding around the IMG tags that HHW cannot handle.

Possible solutions:

- In Word: Deselect the option 'Rely on VML for displaying graphics in browsers' (Tools > Options > General > Web Options)
- In Word: Save as 'filtered HTML'.
- In HHW: Manually add the images to the project's [FILES] section.

Let me know if any of this helps.

More information can be found in the [HTML Help 1.X FAQ](http://helpware.net/FAR/far_faq.htm#wordhtml)

Comment: Saving the Word document as 'Web Page, Filtered' did the trick. Thanks!